This is about ionic's ion-datetime-button
Adding the ionic-datetime-button to the html file No ionic-datetime instance found for ID 'datetime'. I encounter the error
 No ion-datetime instance found for ID 'datetime'

The following files are ionic info,ts,html.
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 8.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 17.3.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 17.3.6
   @angular/cli                  : 17.3.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 11.0.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 6.0.0
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 6.0.0
   @capacitor/ios     : 6.0.0

ts
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {
  ....
  IonDatetime,
  IonDatetimeButton,
  ...
} from '@ionic/angular/standalone';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-schedule',
  templateUrl: './edit-schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-schedule.component.scss'],
  providers: [ModalController],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ...
    IonDatetime,
    IonDatetimeButton,
    ...
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class EditScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

html
<div class="item-style date-style">
        <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>
        <ion-modal>
          <ng-template>
            <ion-datetime
              id="datetime"
              [value]="editEvent.firstDate"
            ></ion-datetime>
          </ng-template>
        </ion-modal>
      </div>

I have changed ionic to standalone and searched for issues but could not find a good answer

When using datetime-button you need to always add keepContentsMounted on the ion-modal or ion-popover inside which ion-datetime component is defined. You can read more on this in ionic documentation for ion-datetime-button component.
<div class="item-style date-style">
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>
  <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
    <ng-template>
      <ion-datetime
        id="datetime"
        [value]="editEvent.firstDate"
      ></ion-datetime>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
</div>


Thanks for the reply.
I tried that code, but I get the following error.
detail-schedule.component.ts:38 [Ionic Error]: No ion-datetime instance found for ID 'datetime'.

@mizuki It should work, if you will try the same in the https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.html, and remove [keepContentsMounted]="true" from the ion-modal then it will through the same error that you are currently getting, as other than that everything is correct.
